# Regex for email

Tags: regex

I have specific rules for local and domain part of email.
**Email local part:**
-Latin letters are allowed: A to Z and a to z
-Number are allowed: 0 to 9
-Following special characters are allowed: !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~
-Dot “.” is allowed but must not be the first or the last character and two dots must not appear consecutively.
-Following Latin characters with diacritics are allowed: àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ
-Other characters are not allowed
-64 characters length maximum

**Email domain** 
must match the requirements for a hostname, a list of dot-separated DNS labels, each label being limited to a length of 63 characters and with the following rules:
-Latin letters are allowed: A to Z and a to z
-Number are allowed: 0 to 9
-Hyphen “-“ is allowed but must not be the first or the last character 
-Following Latin characters with diacritics are allowed: àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ
-Other characters are not allowed
-Total email address: 256 characters length maximum

I am using below regex. Could anyone verify and suggest to make it short if possible.

/^[a-zA-ZA-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~]+)*@(?:a-zA-ZA-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9?.)+a-z0-9?$/;

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Using a regex for email is a bad idea because (1) it's massively complex and (2) it only covers format, meaning there are still a massive number of email addresses which are invalid since they have no backing account behind them. If you want to know if an email address is truly valid (format, exists, has someone monitoring it, etc), send an email to it requiring some action.

Comment: I edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @paxdiablo I agree with you but when you know regex symbols I think not that difficult. Also, in my case I have set of rules so I am not bother about massive emails of other format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked https://regex101.com/ for understanding my regex and got it.

Comment: ^([^.])([a-zA-ZA-zàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9.!#$%&'+=?^_`{|}~/-])+([^.])@[a-zA-ZA-zàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9]+([a-zA-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ0-9.-]+([a-zA-Z0-9]))$